# Sympy polynomial change domain to integers with base m

Tags: sympy, symbolic-math, algebra, polynomials

How can I specify `Poly` in `sympy` to be on certain domain.

For example, integers based on 7, e.g, $\mathbb{Z}_7$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if sympy has $Z_7$, but suppose you wanted $GF(2),$ the Galois field with 2 elements.  Then you can:

```
>>> from sympy import Poly
>>> Poly(x**2 + 2*x, domain=GF(2))
Poly(x**2, x, modulus=2)
```